# Oracle Patch Level Differences (Oracle Enterprise Manager and DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

There is a difference in the patch level that I am seeing on my Oracle database. On the Oracle Enterprise Manager, it shows that it is patched up to .7 but on DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY it does not show any of the patches.

```
APPLY   SERVER  11.2.0.4    0   Patchset 11.2.0.2.0 PSU
APPLY   SERVER  11.2.0.4    0   Patchset 11.2.0.2.0 PSU
```

Is this a common occurrence?

Thank you

Comment: what patch are you checking for? in OEM, are you checking for patch recommendations?

Comment: I'm looking for 11.2.0.4.7 (20760982). On OEM it shows that this patch was installed on Feb 7,2016 10:42:08 AM GMT. On OEM it also shows .1 through .6 as well

Comment: shows .1 through .6 as what? recommended patches or applied patches?

Comment: It shows them as Installed as well, with Installation Times as well

Comment: what does opatch output show? Does it show you have applied 20760982?

Comment: I don't have access to opatch.. My security team says the database is not patched because the tool looks at the DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY table but the DBA says the database is patched all the way to 20760982. I can get the opatch information and report back when I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation of a PSU is not complete without the execution of the postinstall script. Opatch works at file level, it replaces/relinks files in the Oracle home. Changes inside the database are performed by running the postinstall script. Sometimes I see DBAs forget this step.

The postinstall script maintains the `SYS.REGISTRY$` table (on which the `DBA_SERVER_REGISTRY` view is built) with the actual patch versions.

In 11.2, you run the postinstall script as (stated in the README):

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
@?/rdbms/admin/catbundle psu apply
```

This populates the above table (and so the view) with the actual data. When installing a PSU, this script must be executed in all databases running from the affected Oracle Home.

In most of the cases, skipping the postinstall script does not cause any problem, so mostly this goes on unnoticed. But there are exceptions, for example I have seen a database throwing ORA-07445 errors during the configuration of GoldenGate, because the postinstall script was not executed after the installation of the PSU.

Starting with 12c, the postinstall script is executed as:

```
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
cd $ORACLE_HOME/OPatch
./datapatch
```